# Basic example using labels and gesture recognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to create a basic project that uses labels and gesture recognition but am having a little difficulty. I created an interface of 4 UILabels positioned vertically along the center of the app screen. Looks something like:

Question

Next Question

Answer

Show Answer

...just 4 labels, positioned one after the next. I make connections from Interface Builder to my `ViewController.h` file to create IBOutlet properties for each of the labels. Simple enough. I then go ahead and write all the implementation code in the `.m` file (seen below). The only issue is when the app runs, all that is displayed is four positioned labels with the default "Label" text from Interface Builder. The gesture recognizers I added to two of the labels do not seem to be connected/triggering either.

Hoping someone could shed a little light on the issue for me. What started as a simple exercise is driving me a little mad.

Here's my Viewcontroller.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelQuestion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelNextQuestion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAnswer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelShowAnser;

@end
```

And here's my Viewcontroller.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *arrayQuestions;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *arrayAnswers;
@property (assign) int incrementer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // First create the datasource arrays with five elements each
    self.arrayQuestions = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.arrayQuestions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Who am I?", @"Who are you?", @"Where are we?", @"What's going on?", @"Why is this happening?", nil];

    self.arrayAnswers = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.arrayAnswers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Damian", @"Dmitri", @"I don't know.", @"You tell me.", @"I have no clue", nil];

    // Reset the incrementer's value
    self.incrementer = 0;

    // Next configure the labels
    self.labelQuestion = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.labelQuestion.text = [self.arrayQuestions objectAtIndex:self.incrementer];

    self.labelNextQuestion = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(nextQuestionLabelPressed)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.labelNextQuestion addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    self.labelNextQuestion.text = @"Show next question";

    self.labelAnswer = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.labelAnswer.text = @"?????";

    self.labelShowAnser = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.labelShowAnser.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapp = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showAnswerLabelPressed)];
    [tapp setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.labelShowAnser addGestureRecognizer:tapp];
    self.labelShowAnser.text = @"Show answer";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)nextQuestionLabelPressed {
    self.incrementer++;
    self.labelQuestion.text = [self.arrayQuestions objectAtIndex:self.incrementer];
    self.labelAnswer.text = @"?????";
}

- (void)showAnswerLabelPressed {
    self.labelAnswer.text = [self.arrayAnswers objectAtIndex:self.incrementer];
}

@end
```

Comment: Well I did try setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for both labels but it didn't make any difference. But the labels being displayed don't contain the text I set them to programatically. They just say "Label"

Comment: And I've explained why in my answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've connected a label from the storyboard to `self.labelQuestion`. So far so good. When you launch, `self.labelQuestion` points to the label from the storyboard, which is the one that you see in the visible interface of the running app.

But then you say:

```
self.labelQuestion = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

That *disconnects* the outlet and *replaces* the value of that variable (`self.labelQuestion`) with a new blank label! So anything you now do to `labelQuestion` cannot possibly affect the one from the storyboard, as you have broken the connection.

You do that for all four labels, so you have smashed all four outlets into dust. Thus, your other code has no effect on the visible labels, which come from the storyboard.

Just delete all four `[[UILabel alloc] init]` lines, and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew there was some nuance I was overlooking. I took out the `[[UILabel alloc] init]` statements and everything is now operating smoothly. I did have to go and add the second `userInteractionEnabled` parameter to make it 100%.